# How to launch a TTTableView based view with TTLauncherView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I'm very newbie with Three20. I'm trying to make an TTLauncherView based interface, without success for now.

My LauncherView contains a button, mapped to an URL. When I click on this button, I want a TTTableView based to be displayed on screen. But I have nothing.

Here is a piece of my AppDelegate code :

```
[map from:@"tt://rank" toViewController:[RankController class]];
```

And the LauncherView code (a piece, too) :

```
launcherView.pages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[[TTLauncherItem alloc]    
                         initWithTitle:@"Rank"
                         image:@"bundle://defaultMusic.png"
                         URL:@"tt://rank"
                         canDelete:YES] autorelease],nil], nil];
```

The button is here, no problem. But when clicked, it never opens my RankController class. Here is its source :

```
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
        {
            self.title = @"Rank";
            self.variableHeightRows = YES;
        }

        return self;
    }

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) createModel
{
    NSLog(@"rank");
    self.dataSource = [TTSectionedDataSource dataSourceWithObjects:
                       @"Items",
                       [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Item n°1" URL:nil],
                       [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Item n°2" URL:nil],
                       [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Item n°3" URL:nil],
                       [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Item n°4" URL:nil],
                       [TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Item n°5" URL:nil],
                       nil];

}
```

I tried to proceed the same way that the examples packaged in Three20, so what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the TTLauncherViewDelegate.
In your .h file, declare your view controller to implement the TTLauncherViewDelegate:

```
@interface SFLauncherViewController : TTViewController <TTLauncherViewDelegate>
```

Then in .m file, implement this method:

```
- (void)launcherView:(TTLauncherView *)launcher didSelectItem:(TTLauncherItem *)item{
    NSLog(@"did select item: %@", [item URL]);
    TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];

    TTURLAction *action = [[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:[item URL]] applyAnimated:YES];

    [navigator openURLAction:action];
}
```