# TTLauncherView url to view controllers? - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, three20, launcher

Hey, I would like to know how to link a view controller to a item in the TTLauncher?

```
[self launcherItemWithTitle:@"Apple" image:@"bundle://safari_logo.png" URL://What to write here?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You link it to a URL in your TTURLMap that is linked to the view controller you want.  So you'd call for example:

```
[self launcherItemWithTitle:@"Apple" image:@"bundle://safari_logo.png" URL:@"tt://apple"]
```

and then when you declare your TTURLMAP:

```
TTNavigator *navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
[navigator.URLMap from:@"tt://apple" toViewController:[YourViewController class]];
```

where `YourViewController` is the one you want to launch

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, diddn't work. I got two errors and one warning. Basically all of the added lines.

Comment: Help? What is this? Has it someting to do with what I want? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934075/how-to-launch-a-tttableview-based-view-with-ttlauncherview

Comment: Warning: Unused variable 'navigator'.
Error: Expected ':' before '[' token. 
Error: 'navigator' undeclared (first use in this function).

Comment: ah misspelled navigator on first line.  I've fixed it.  I'm just typing this free-hand, I'm not able to compile this :)